# DoubleRenderError after send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have strange problem in this code snippet:

```
def export_csv
    user = User.find_by_u_token(params[:u])
    return render json: {status: 'error', descr: 'INVALID_U_TOKEN'} if !user
    return render json: {status: 'error', descr: 'INVALID_DELIMITER'} if !user.csv_del
    return render json: {status: 'error', descr: 'PARAMS_NOT_DEFINED'} if !params[:invoices]
    return render json: {status: 'error', descr: 'INVALID_USER_TYPE'} if !user.contractor? && !user.customer?

    invoices = invoices_for_user(user)
    pinvoices = params[:invoices].split(' ')

    return render json: {status: 'error', descr: 'INVALID_INVOICES'} if !check_invoices(invoices, pinvoices)

    export_invoices(pinvoices, user.csv_del)
    send_file("file.csv")

    return render json: {status: 'ok'}
end
```

My `export_invoices` method:

```
def export_invoices(pinvoices, delimiter)
    CSV.open("file.csv", "wb", {:col_sep => delimiter}) do |csv|
      Invoice.find(pinvoices).each do |i|
        csv << i.attributes.values
      end
    end
end
```

And I have `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.` error.
I've tried to comment the line `send_file("file.csv")` and everything works.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the error message you're getting is telling you you can only call `render` once. 
`send_file` is actually doing a render. You get the error when you reach the last line in your code that does another render.

The question is, what do you expect the code to render in the end? is it the CSV file or the json response? you can't have both. So obviously, you want to remove the line in which you return the json response.

Answer (score 1):

in above code remove the line `return render json: {status: 'ok'}` and create a template export_csv.js.erb here you write your success code

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the

```
return render json: {status: 'ok'}
```

Reason it will work :
  cause send_file itself will render, so it doesn't make any sense to do that again.